# browse a table and share it on 2 tables in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a table that follows a defined sequence that Repite : [ col , name , value1, value2 , value 3, col, name value1, value2, value3 ..col , name , value1, value2 , value 3 ]

code:

```
 var data =["DN","Atac","1","2","3","PDA","Atac","5","6","7","EPDA","Atac","8","9","11","DN Potentielle","Atac","14","4","8"] ;
```

I try to split the data table col , name , values:
Code result :

```
var column = ["DN","PDA","EPDA","DN Potentielle"];
var name ="Atac";
var values =[ "1","2","3","5","6","7","8","9","11","14","4","8"];
```

how has the simplest  method without a lot of code to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that your data is consistent and can rely on the structure you wrote, the simplest thing would be:

```
var column = [];
var name = [];
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i = i+5) {
    column.push(data[i]);
    name.push(data[i+1]);
    values.push(data[i+2]);
    values.push(data[i+3]);
    values.push(data[i+4]);
};

name = name.filter(function(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
});

console.log(column); //["DN","PDA","EPDA","DN Potentielle"]
console.log(name); //["Atac"]
console.log(values); //["1", "2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "11", "14", "4", "8"]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ukjpmq3/)

Answer (score 0):

Set up an object to hold the values:

```
var obj = { column: [], name: null, values: [] };
```

Then cycle over the array in groups of 5, adding the various elements to the object:

```
for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i+=5) {
  obj.column.push(data[i]);
  obj.name = data[i + 1];

  // push.apply is a neat way of concatenation that doesn't
  // require the creation of a new variable
  obj.values.push.apply(obj.values, data.slice(i + 2, i + 5));
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/erfd8vv8/)

Answer (score 0):

I try to figure out what you want, and the best way is to retrieve the number value and string value without spliting it.

```
var data =["DN","Atac","1","2","3","PDA","Atac","5","6","7","EPDA","Atac","8","9","11","DN Potentielle","Atac","14","4","8"] ;
var columns = [];
var values = [];
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
    var parsedValue = parseInt(data[k]);
    if ( ! isNaN(parsedValue) ) {
        values.push(parsedValue);
    } else {
        columns.push(v);
    }

});
console.log(columns);
console.log(values);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bzryqs84/1/

Comment: The OP doesn't mention jQuery anywhere in the question or tags.